# How to speed up a searching algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two different catalogues (`data_in` and `data_out`) with `x,y` coordinates of many points. As shown below I need to find all `data_in` points that are near to `data_out` points, in particular all `data_in` points within a circle of radius `r_search`, centered on every `data_out` points.

This little script works fine, but it is very slow. There is a way to speed up the process?

```
import numpy as np

data_in = np.genfromtxt(file_in)
x_in = np.array(data_in[:,1])
y_in = np.array(data_in[:,2])

data_out = np.genfromtxt(file_out)
x_out = np.array(data_out[:,1])
y_out = np.array(data_out[:,2])

r_search = 5

a=0
for i in range(len(x_out)):
    for j in range(len(x_in)):
                delta_x = abs(x_in[j] - x_out[i])
                delta_y = abs(y_in[j] - y_out[i])
                r_tmp = np.sqrt(np.power(delta_x,2) + np.power(delta_y,2))
                if (r_tmp <= r_search):
                    a=a+1

X = np.zeros(a)
Y = np.zeros(a)
a=0
for i in range(len(x_out)):
    for j in range(len(x_in)):
                delta_x = abs(x_in[j] - x_out[i])
                delta_y = abs(y_in[j] - y_out[i])
                r_tmp = np.sqrt(np.power(delta_x,2) + np.power(delta_y,2))
                if (r_tmp <= r_search):
                    X[a] = x_in[j]
                    Y[a] = y_in[j]
                    a=a+1
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a [KD-tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html).

Comment: How about a [quad tree](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/1679-quadtrees-and-octrees.html)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest algorithm for the application you describe is a [k-dimensional tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), in particular, a 2-dimensional tree, better known as [quad-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). The way it works is by partitioning the big array you have into smaller arrays containing groups of close points.

Implementing it yourself is possible but not recommended since there are libraries that are way more optimised than you could do yourself.
There were [some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298517/are-any-of-these-quad-tree-libraries-any-good) on SO some years ago on which is the best. But now it is acceptable to say that [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree) library is the best.

Comment: `scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point` in particular seems very good!

Answer (score 1):

One possible optimisation is to remove the (expensive) square root from the distance calculation and compare with the squared search radius, so this:

```
r_tmp = np.sqrt(np.power(delta_x,2) + np.power(delta_y,2))
if (r_tmp <= r_search):
```

becomes:

```
r_tmp = np.power(delta_x,2) + np.power(delta_y,2)
if (r_tmp <= r_search*r_search):
```